# Wait for Rethinkdb promise to return a result before returning parent function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rethinkdb

I'm calling a function which returns an object after querying a database. But I'm struggling to get the function to wait the database to return a result before returning the final data.

Please can someone suggest how to wait for the database query to finish?

```
addBasket: function(prodId, cookie) {
   var nextCookie = cookie;
   db.table('Events').filter({id: prodId}).pluck('eventName').run().then(function(result){
       newData.prodName = result[0].eventName;
       nextCookie.basket.push(newData);
       return nextCookie;
   }).error(function(err){
       return;
   })
}
```

Comment: You'll want to `return` the promise from `addBasket` so that you can wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to make addBasket return a promise

```
var funcs = {
    addBasket: function(prodId, cookie) {
       var nextCookie = cookie;
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         db.table('Events').filter({id: prodId}).pluck('eventName').run().then(function(result){
             newData.prodName = result[0].eventName;
             nextCookie.basket.push(newData);
             resolve(nextCookie);
         }).error(reject)
      });
    }
}
```

then you can do

`funcs.addBasket(..args).then(function(nextCookie){....})`